# ServerSide: Reading until an "end" String is entered from the client

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I am a beginner at writing in Java, sorry if the question is stupid.. Well the problem I encountered is when I am writing the text from my ClientSide, it doesn't seem to get through the while loop properly in the ServerSide. Could you please give some directions on how to solve it. Thanks in advance!

```
public void enterMessage() throws IOException {
    String topic;
    String currentLine = "", text = "";
    String receiver;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    int id = messages.lastIndexOf(messages);
    out.writeUTF("The users you can message are: " + Server.users.toString() + "\nEnter the user you want to message: ");
    receiver = in.readUTF();
    for (int i = 0; i < Server.users.size(); i++) {         
        if(receiver.equals(Server.users.get(i).username)) {
            out.writeUTF("You are writing to: " + Server.users.get(i).username + "\nEnter the topic: ");
            topic = in.readUTF();
            out.writeUTF("Enter your message(write 'end' on a new line to finish): ");
            do {
                currentLine = br.readLine();
                text.concat(currentLine);
            }
           while(!currentLine.equalsIgnoreCase("end"));
            //Server.sendToUser(receiver);
            Message msg = new Message(username,receiver,id,topic,text);
            messages.add(msg);
            out.writeUTF("Message saved.");
            break;
    }
        else
            out.writeUTF("This user does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bring `currentLine = br.readLine();` out of while loop like:

```
currentLine = br.readLine();
while(!currentLine.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
```

Reason being:

You initialized currentLine as empty string and you will only change currentLine when you enter while loop which checks for condition like is "empty string" equal to "end" which will never happen and your code will not enter while loop.

Comment: I did try initializing it with a value, even swapped to do-while, still it gets stuck somewhere, could it be related to the BufferedReader?

Comment: Paste your updated code in your question and notify once done.

Comment: do { currentLine = br.readLine();
     text.concat(currentLine);
}   while(!currentLine.equalsIgnoreCase("end"));

Comment: update your question by modifying the code like above. I am not able to get where exactly you have do while loop now.

Comment: I just swapped to do-while so currentLine does not get a null or isEmpty value.

Comment: Do you ever enter `if(receiver.equals(Server.users.get(i).username)) {`?

Comment: what is `socket.getInputStream()`? are you expecting input form socket or from user?

Comment: From the connected user's socket.

Comment: And is socket providing the input? which i am assuming no and hence it gets blocked in your call `currentLine = br.readLine();`.

Comment: Thank you gonna look into that.